# I am trying to route between 2 stateful pages in flutter but its giving me an error How can I solve it

Tags: flutter-navigation

The error its giving is "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>' in a const constructor."
How can I route between the widgets without an error.

this is the code I tried and it won't work any solutions

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'PoultryCalc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Poultry Calc',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: PoultryCalc(),

    routes: {
      '/' : (context) =>  PoultryCalc(),
      '/second' : (context) =>  Records(),
    },
  ));
}
```